# Is the Stack Overflow website down?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Is stackoverflow.com not accessible? I am having hard time accessing it. It gives me a undefined status in the http trace.

Comment: You aren't crazy, it was not responding for me at around the same time, seemed to be out for about 10 minutes (during which time other SE sites seemed to be responding normally).

Answer (score 5):

No, SO is working perfectly. In the future you can use [this](http://www.isup.me/stackoverflow.com) to check.

Comment: so how do i know if its for my region or just my computer? And what can be the probable cause of this?

Comment: That was a pretty long URL there, so I shortened it for you. =P

Comment: Try `tracert`/`traceroute`. Beyond that, you won't be able to get a definite answer without a fairly large sample, and MSO isn't the place for that.